# Custom UIAlertController - Application tried to present modally an active controller

Tags: swift, swift3, uialertcontroller

Application tried to present modally an active controller

I'm trying to create custom UIAlertController.
Thus from different places will be easier to work with.
but I'm getting this error :

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modally an active controller

```
class CustomAlert: UIAlertController,  UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate  {

    private static var sheet : UIAlertController = UIAlertController()
    static let instance = CustomAlert()

    func create(title: String, message: String) -> CustomAlert {
        CustomAlert.sheet = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        return self
    }

    func addlibrary() -> CustomAlert{
        let libraryAction = UIAlertAction(title: "library", style: .default, handler: nil)
        CustomAlert.sheet.addAction(libraryAction)
        return self
    }

    func show(on vc : UIViewController){
          UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

Where is the problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to present the wrong controller in your `show` method.

Change:

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

to:

```
vc.present(self, animated: true, completion: nil)
```